# How do I ack-grep exclude file type *.sql files or file size larger than >3MB?

Tags: grep, ack

I want to search my directory for "foo" in the files, but i have these gigantic sql files. How do I exclude these file types or file sizes larger than 3MB using ack-grep? Also how would this be done with grep?

Comment: `ack foo --nosql` will ignore anything with a .sql extension.  To see more about the filetypes ack supports, see `ack --help-types`.  ack has no way of filtering on file size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about `ack-grep` but you can use `find` to exclude files larger than 3MB.

```
find . -size -3M -exec grep "foo" {} \;
```

Comment: what does {} and the slash \ stand for in that grep command?

Comment: `{}` is the placeholder for the file names "found" by find. `\;` escapes the semicolon and makes it a terminal semicolon of the `-exec` command of find instead the shell. See `man find` or just google some simple tutorial on `find`. It's a very powerful and useful command line tool.

Comment: Use `-exec grep "foo" {} +` to make grep output the names of the matched files.

Answer (score 13):

According to the [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/) doc and man page
you can ignore files with a particular extension by using `--ignore-file=`*filter* where *filter* is *filtertype:filterargs*. One of the *filtertypes* is `ext` for file extension. So try

```
--ignore-file=ext:sql
```

or since sql is one of the built-in types, you can just use

```
--nosql
```

Comment: To see all the file types recognizes, see `ack --help-types`.